# How to insert into database using ajax on php?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have html form with three values fname,lname,age. I want to send it on server side php file and insert into database.

My html form is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function insert(fname,lname,age)
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_db_php.php?fname=fname&lname=lname&age=age",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<table>

<tr><td>First Name : </td><td> <input type="text" fname="fname"/> </td> </tr>
<tr><td>Last Name : </td><td> <input type="text" fname="lname"/> </td> </tr>
<tr><td>City : </td><td> <input type="text" fname="age"/> </td> </tr>

<input type="submit" onclick="insert(fname,lname,age)">

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As I have used ajax it should not load entire page, but when I click submit button it load entire page. why?
And php page which receives values and insert into database is:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

$fname=$_GET['fname'];
$lname=$_GET['lname'];
$age=$_GET['age'];

//echo "firstname : " $fname;

$con=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306' ,'root','root','my_db');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$sql="INSERT INTO table1 (fname, lname, age)
VALUES
('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[age]')";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";
mysqli_close($con);


?>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click the submit button it shows nothing, no error and no update in database too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change as said by Nikola
then 
Change in HTML

```
input type="submit"
```

to

```
input type="button"
```

This will not reload the page.
Then
Remove below tags from PHP

```
<html>
<body>
</html>
</body>
```

**I'll recommend use jQuery to make ajax calls.**

Update how to use ajax and serialize:

This is test.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        alert("Hello");
        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test2.php",
        data: data
        }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<table>

<tr><td>First Name : </td><td> <input type="text" name="fname"/> </td> </tr>
<tr><td>Last Name : </td><td> <input type="text" name="lname"/> </td> </tr>
<tr><td>City : </td><td> <input type="text" name="age"/> </td> </tr>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is test2.php

```
<?php
if($_GET)
{
$fname=$_GET['fname'];
$lname=$_GET['lname'];
$age=$_GET['age'];

echo "firstname : ".$fname;
}
?>
```

Comment: @ Vivek: This does not make any change! Same problem yet. Reloadin problem solved but main prob still up!

Comment: i think change this line xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_db_php.php?fname=fname&lname=lname&age=age",true); as xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_db_php.php?fname="+fname+"&lname="+lname+"&age="+age+",true);

Comment: your code seems fine, are you sure ajax call is made to server? use jquery to make ajax calls. See here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I am new to php and ajax, dont know exactly that code is correct or not!

Comment: ok wait i'll update my answer

Comment: check the updated code it has two files test.php and test2.php

Comment: Vivek Muthal: When I run this it shows hello alert, code stops working after $ajax block start! And how does it store fname,lname,age into database? We have not specified it in updated code!

Comment: yes, i have not written database code. It's will alert "Hello" then ajax call is made then it will alert "fname" cause in php i am echoing it fname. Your ajax is not working try with different browser. the above code work's fine at my end.

Comment: Using a submit was good idea, And another issue was I was mixing mysql and mysqli. I just used mysqli then it started working currectly!

Answer (score 1):

You set `$fname`, `$lname` and `$age` correctly, but you never use them, instead of that you use `$_POST` variables which do not exist.

Instead of 
`('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[age]')";`

you should use the `$_GET` variables e.g.

`('$fname','$lname','$age')";`

---

I'd also suggest you to escape the strings when adding them to the database. One possible solution can be [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @ Nikola: I updated it : $sql="INSERT INTO table1 (fname, lname, age)
VALUES
('$_GET[fname]','$_GET[lname]','$_GET[age]')";

But not change!